# How to enforce users to input user account's fields after user registeration?

Tags: users

I'm useing D7.

What I want to do is...

Step1: Let users register only by inputting their email address & password on  user registration form (http://www.my_website.com/user/register)

Step2: Redirect them to user account edit page (http://www.my_website.com/user/user id/edit) after their registration. And then, enforce them to input the rest of fields such as [first_name] & [hobby] on the edit page.

The 'step1' was able to be done by using  'Email Registration' & 'User registration password' module. And I think I can redirect users to the edit page. But I don't know how to enforce them to complete the rest of fields in edit page.

I want to do this without using Profile2 module. Does anybody have idea to do that?

I'm really sorry if this is an entry-level question to you. But I'm very new to Drupal and I have been struggling with this for a week, but I couldn't find the way. Please somebody help me!

Thank you!

Comment: ?Have you tried the module [Complete profile](https://www.drupal.org/project/complete_profile). It says: ... this module will force the user to complete their profile before they can continue using the site.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Rules. You could add a new field into the users' accounts that is `Completed Profile Fields` and it could be a single boolean or possabily a `multi-value field`.

Then your rule could check:

- If login, or page load -- has user completed profile fields? If yes, continue to any page -- else show a `profile form page` (not necessarily their account page).
- I'm not sure it would be easy to do this globally, or test the profiles have been filled prior to going to a `/node/add` page for instance.
- After filling in the profile values the Rule could update the user account field `completed profile fields` to `True`.

If you don't want users to see this `completed profile fields` field -- you can install and use [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions).

**EDIT**

If you dont want the user to see this special `completed profile fields` but still want the rule to update the value you may need to set the `uid` of the user updating this field. I do this usually by creating a fake user for the system called like `mysite-system-user` and give him a special role called `system role` for instance.

Comment: Thank you so much, tenken!
After all, I used differrent way than the one you suggested.
That was using Profile2. I wanted to know the way without using the Profile2 module because I didn't know how to set particular fields(not all fields) on profile with it. But now, I fond how to do...
But, Thank you anyway. I really appreciate your kindness!